# Уведомления с поддержкой старых версий андроид

Tags: android

Как сделать уведомление с поддержкой старых версий андроид (api 16, 17 ..). У меня в тестовом сервисе есть метод, который строит уведомление на поздних версиях андроид все работает (андроид 5,6,7), а на андроид 4.4 и ниже появляется ошибка какая-то. Не ругайте строго я новичок

Метод для создания уведомления

```
private void showNotify() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(MyConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    closeIntent.setAction(MyConstants.ACTION.STOP_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Тестовый заголовок")
            .setContentText("Описание")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, "Закрыть", pCloseIntent)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    startForeground(MyConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
}
```

Ошибка

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package androidapp.testapp: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=androidapp.testapp id=101 tag=null score=0 notn=Notification(pri=0 contentView=androidapp.testapp/0x109008f vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null] 1 action) user=UserHandle{0})
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас падает из-за `Action` кнопки (`addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, "Закрыть", pCloseIntent`), который не работает на старых версиях, вам нужно ветвиться в коде примерно так:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    //нотификации с экшн кнопкой
}
else  {
    //нотификации без экшн кнопки
}
```

Comment: Попробую сейчас. Спасибо

Comment: Убрал кнопку все остальное оставил и прописал условие как вы сказали. Все равно вылетает на андроид 4.4

Comment: Это по любому связано с `ACTION` - уберите из кода все `setAction()`

Comment: Я указал чтобы если версия больше чем KITKAT запускать нотификацию с кнопкой все заработало. Только теперь как для старых версий сделать так чтобы если свайпом убираешь уведомление то сервис останавливался

Comment: Вам нужен `setDeleteIntent()` он срабатывает при смахивании нотификации